# What's the Developer Express equivalent of System.Windows.Forms.LinkButton?

Tags: devexpress

I can't seem to find Developer Express' version of the `LinkButton`.  (The Windows Forms linkbutton, not the `ASP.NET` linkbutton.)  `HyperLinkEdit` doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for since it looks like a TextEdit/TextBox.

Anyone know what their version of it is?  I'm using the latest DevX controls: 8.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control is called the HyperLinkEdit.  You have to adjust the properties to get it to behave like the System.Windows.Forms control like so:

```
    control.BorderStyle = BorderStyles.NoBorder;
    control.Properties.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    control.Properties.AppearanceFocused.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    control.Properties.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: So ... why not just use the standard LinkButton?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use the standard ASP.Net LinkButton, unless it's really missing something you need.